# Updating Ubuntu Virtual Machine using putty

Tags: updates, virtualization, putty

I have access to a virtual machine running a clean install of Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS. However, I need to use Ubuntu 14.04, and the server administrator is fine with me updating it. My only access to the server is through putty. I don't know that much about Ubuntu so I would like to hear your thoughts first.

Is it even possible to update Ubuntu using this setup? What commands would I need to do it? Would I need to do anything special as compared to an update of a normal (non-VM) server?

**EDIT:** Following user283885's advice and https://www.linode.com/docs/security/upgrading/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-12-04-precise I've upgraded to 12.04. Now I'm in the middle of upgrading to 14.04 and I get the following 'A new version of configuration file /etc/default/grub is available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified'. The differences are included in the image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/7byc3.jpg. (I would like to post it, but don't have enough rep.)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not be able to because of how many releases are in between, however, you need to install

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
```

Once that's installed, I suggest you install tmux as well, since it's easyer to work with than screen

```
 sudo apt-get install tmux
```

Now, you can start a tmux session by just typing in `tmux` .

Note to self, if you have custom network setup ( bonds and bridges) be advised that the way those are written changes in between distros. I advise you rever that to a dumb and simple 1 interface layout temporary out of fear of locking you out after upgrades. If networking is misswritten it will not start network on reboot.

Now in tmux run `sudo do-release-upgrade` and follow the prompts. If for some reason the connection drops, relog on putty and type `tmux attach` to resume the session.

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, I've run into something that I don't know how to handle. See the update on my original post.

Comment: You can go on with the upgrade, accepting the new version of grub file, it's ok.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention that it's recommended to accept whatever the package manager pushes for defaults and then adjust based on updated configs.